# "Use of unresolved identifier" using the new Swift 2.2 syntax for selectors on implicit setter

Tags: swift

Migrating my code to Swift 2.2, I have a property `var activeTextField:UITextfield?` and the selector I was using was `"setActiveTextField:"`. This method does not exist explicitly in my swift code.

With the new syntax, `#selector(setActiveTextField)` doesn't work: `Use of unresolved identifier`

I know I could use `Selector("setActiveTextField:")` but I'd loose the benefit of the new swift selectors.

So, what's the new way of doing this?

Comment: I have no method setActiveTextField, it's the implicit obj-c setter.

Comment: He probably has to use "#selector(setActiveTextField(_:))". Using my phone so I can't format the code properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but since it's an implicit obj-c setter, it actually doesn't exist in swift.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler suggest the proper syntax?

Comment: He suggest `Selector("setActiveTextField:")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you're working with a property, not a method. This has two problems:

- The ObjC setter/getter method pair for a property is generated at run time.
- The `#selector` expression requires a Swift function/method reference.

When Swift compiles your source, it doesn't know that the ObjC `-(UITextField*)activeTextField` and `-(void)setActiveTextField:(UITextField*)field` methods will exist, so it can't generate function references for them. Since it can't generate a function reference, it doesn't have something it can use for the `#selector` expression.

For now, there isn't a way to use `#selector` to access property getters/setters — using `Selector(...)` with a string constant is your only option.

(This is actually just a new face on a longstanding known issue... it's the same reason you also can't pass a property getter/setter to something like `map` or `filter`. I think I've seen something on http://bugs.swift.org about this, but I'm not finding it at the moment.)

Comment: I posted a bug on the jira (SR-1029), someone answered that there was a discussion on going on swift-evolution to provide a synthax for refering to setters & getters. So it's seems that i'll have to stick with `Selector()` for now .

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3, [SE-0064](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0064-property-selectors.md) was accepted to solve this problem. Now, you would generate that setter like so:

```
#selector(setter: activeTextField)
```